# Android - How to Load More then 20mb Image in Imageview

Tags: android, android-bitmap

My project is about image processing in Android. My problem is that when I load a 22MB image in an ImageView I get an OutOfMemoryError.

Error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 244588824 byte
>   allocation with 11397108 free bytes and 79MB until OOM at
>   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file:

```
<application 
       ...
       android:largeHeap="true" 
       ...
       >
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need resize your image and load subsample to imageview: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

You can use some lib as Picaso, Glide to do that.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but i don't wan't to reduce image size of resolution. using bitmap resolution will be changed. any other idea about this.

Comment: Using:   Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .override(original_width, original_height)
        .into(myImageView);